# MySql return rows with highest value, created on or before a date

Tags: mysql

I have the following table ([SQFiddle, with sample data here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5faa5f/6)):

```
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| id |data_date   | value | score |     created_at      |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 2015-01-01 | 10    |  10   | 2016-07-01 09:00:00 |
| 2  | 2015-02-01 | 10    |  10   | 2016-07-01 09:00:00 |
| 3  | 2015-03-01 | 10    |  10   | 2016-07-01 09:00:00 |
| 4  | 2015-01-01 | 15    |  20   | 2016-07-02 09:00:00 |
| 5  | 2015-03-01 | 15    |  20   | 2016-07-02 09:00:00 |
| 6  | 2015-03-01 | 15    |  15   | 2016-07-03 09:00:00 |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
```

What I'd like to do, is to return a single record for each `data_data`, having the highest score on a given `created_at` date.

The expected result for results on 2016-07-02 would be:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| id |data_date   | value | score |     created_at      |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| 4  | 2015-01-01 | 15    |  20   | 2016-07-02 09:00:00 |
| 2  | 2015-02-01 | 10    |  10   | 2016-07-01 09:00:00 |
| 5  | 2015-03-01 | 15    |  20   | 2016-07-02 09:00:00 |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
```

What I've achieved so far is to return the single highest scored record for each `data_data`, but I can't seem to add the right condition to factor in the `created_at` field.

```
select `my_table`.* 
from `my_table` 
left outer join `my_table` as `t2` 
on `my_table`.`data_date` = `t2`.`data_date` AND 
(
    (`my_table`.`score` < `t2`.`score`) OR 
    (`my_table`.`score` = `t2`.`score` AND `my_table`.`id` < `t2`.`id`)
) 
where `t2`.`data_date` is null 
order by `my_table`.`data_date` asc
```

This returns the following results:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| id |data_date   | value | score |     created_at      |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| 4  | 2015-01-01 | 15    |  20   | 2016-07-02 09:00:00 |
| 2  | 2015-02-01 | 10    |  10   | 2016-07-01 09:00:00 |
| 6  | 2015-03-01 | 15    |  15   | 2016-07-03 09:00:00 |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
```

Using a query like the following, to get all records created on or before 2nd July with the highest score:

```
select `my_table`.* 
from `my_table` 
left outer join `my_table` as `t2` 
on `my_table`.`data_date` = `t2`.`data_date` AND 
(
    (`my_table`.`score` < `t2`.`score`) OR 
    (`my_table`.`score` = `t2`.`score` AND `my_table`.`id` < `t2`.`id`)
) AND
DATE_FORMAT(my_table.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2016-07-02' AND
DATE_FORMAT(t2.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2016-07-02'
where `t2`.`data_date` is null 
order by `my_table`.`data_date` asc
```

Returns the following incorrect result (row 6 should not be returned):

```
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| id |data_date   | value | score |     created_at      |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| 4  | 2015-01-01 | 15    |  20   | 2016-07-02 09:00:00 |
| 2  | 2015-02-01 | 10    |  10   | 2016-07-01 09:00:00 |
| 5  | 2015-03-01 | 15    |  20   | 2016-07-02 09:00:00 |
| 6  | 2015-03-01 | 15    |  15   | 2016-07-03 09:00:00 |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
```

**In summary**

For a single `data_date`, there may be multiple records, each having a different `value` and a different `score`. I want to return the single row for each `data_data` which has the highest `score` which was created on or before a given date. I.e. if a `data_date` has a record created on each day of the week (Mon-Fri), I may want the highest scored value which was available on the Wednesday for each `data_data`.

Comment: From your description, surely the results for 07-01 are 1,2,3

Comment: You're right. I'd mistyped, fixed in the above question.

Comment: OK, but now I don't understand why 2 would appear in the result at all.

Comment: Because there is no record created on the 2nd July, so to return a complete time series, the highest scored record created on the 1st July is returned.

Comment: Because that's the most recent date in the past?

Answer (score 1):

A fiddle to do this kind of thing is to (ab)use the GROUP_CONCAT function. You can group by the field you need to group by, and use GROUP_CONCAT on each other field, ordered descending by the field you want the max value of. This gets you all the values for each value concatenated together.

You can then use SUBSTRING_INDEX to just get the first value of each one.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY score DESC), ',', 1),
    data_date,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY score DESC), ',', 1),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY score DESC), ',', 1),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(created_at ORDER BY score DESC), ',', 1)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY data_date
```

In this example it is quite easy. When you have text fields that may contain a comma, or you have NULL values then it gets a bit more complicated.

This gets you your existing results in possibly a more efficient way. But I am unsure as to how you are trying to factor in the created_at date, unless you mean you only want to take account of all records from before a certain created_at date:-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY score DESC), ',', 1),
    data_date,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY score DESC), ',', 1),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY score DESC), ',', 1),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(created_at ORDER BY score DESC), ',', 1)
FROM my_table
WHERE created_at <= '2016-07-02 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY data_date
```

EDIT

This 2nd query is getting all the records prior to the end of a specified date (I have used the date / time this way rather than extracting the date part from the value in the column, as this allows an index on the date / time to be used, while extracting the date part prevents any index being used, and also forces the use of a function on every row on the table). For all matching records it groups them by the data_date field. For the id, value, score and created_at fields it uses GROUP_CONCAT to group up all the values for each data_date, with each value separated by a comma (the default), ordered by the score descending.

At his stage for the data_date of 2015-01-01 the id field will contain '*4,1*', value will contain '*15,10*', score will contain '*20,10*' and created_at will contain '*2016-07-02 09:00:00,2016-07-01 09:00:00*' .

SUBSTRING_INDEX is then used to get everything up to the first comma for each of those fields. As they are in descending score order it will get the value for each that corresponds to the highest score.

Comment: For a single ```data_date```, there may be multiple records, each having a different ```value``` and a different ```score```. I want to return the single row for each ```data_data``` which has the highest ```score``` which was created on or before a given date. I.e. if a ```data_date``` has a record created on each day of the week (mon-fri), I may want the highest scored value which was available on the Wednesday. I hope that clears up my question.

Comment: @Amo - in which case I think my 2nd SQL example is what you need (although not tested - sql fiddle crashes out 95% of the time for me whenever I try and use it)

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the second query is doing?

Comment: @Amo - added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT a.data_date
            , a.created_at
            , MAX(a.score) score
         FROM my_table a
         JOIN
            ( SELECT data_date
                   , MAX(created_at) created_at
                FROM my_table
               WHERE created_at <= '2016-07-02 23:59:59'
               GROUP 
                  BY data_date
            ) b
           ON b.data_date = a.data_date
          AND b.created_at = a.created_at
        GROUP
           BY a.data_date
            , a.created_at
     ) y
    ON y.data_date = x.data_date
   AND y.created_at = x.created_at
   AND y.score = x.score;
```

Comment: Are there any benefits to using this query over the one that @Kickstart posted, and can you explain what's going on a little more?

Comment: I couldn't say. My query is very similar to yours, except that it takes account of the additional criteria. As a general rule, an uncorellated subquery will outperform most other ways of achieving the same thing. Plus it's not bound by any limitations associated with GROUP_CONCAT, but that's no reason not to upvote BOTH solutions.

Comment: As I'll be applying this query to a very large data set, I'll run some benchmarks (~2m rows) and accept the query which performs the best as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Amo - it will vary massively depending on the indexes available, and the spread of records.

Comment: @Kickstart I agree, indexes exist on id (PK), score, and created_at

Comment: @Amo - none of those will particularly help my solution. created_at is possibly going to narrow the results down very little if you are checking recent dates. A covering index on data_date and score might help

Answer (score -1):

following query will work fine in your case

```
select max(id), data_date, max(value), max(score), max(created_at) 
 from     
  my_table 
 where score in (select max(score) from my_table group by data_date) 
 group by data_date;
```

Comment: That will give the values for each data_date, rather than the values from the row with the max score